# Re: What cricket jargon has emanated from India?

Tags: support

For reasons best known to himself, Reg Dwight has blocked any further progress on this question by  way of an edict that prohibits anyone voting unless they have already earned 10 points on the question. In such circumstances, how can progress be made? Only activity is allowed from those who have already been active. Seems a bit like 'sour grapes' to me!

Comment: Sour grapes? Reg didn't make the rules. 'Protecting' a question prevents casual (thoughtless) responses commonly made by newcomers. That's all.

Answer (score 7):

I presume you refer to [What Indian words appear in cricket's vocabulary?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133803/what-indian-words-appear-in-crickets-vocabulary).

> that prohibits anyone voting unless they have already earned 10 points on the question.

*Answering*, not voting. Voting limits are defined site-wide as 15 rep required for an upvote and 125 for a downvote.

> In such circumstances, how can progress be made?

10 reputation is not an insurmountable limit.

> For reasons best known to himself

I quote, from the protection info block thingy: "This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users."

> Seems a bit like 'sour grapes' to me!

In what way precisely?

Answer (score 5):

(Take a deep breath and please read this in a conciliatory tone.)

It's actually a positive measure and if you think about it, a compliment. For a question to be "protected" it means it has generated a surge of interest and answers that goes beyond the norm.

It, as waiwai933 pointed out, prevents users who have not gained any reputation points (and even more importantly, spammers) from posting nonsensical answers, answers which really should be comments, and actively discourages abusive and offensive replies (which I imagined happened fairly regularly in the past). Users can still post answers, they just need 10 reputation points. In other words they need to have contributed to the site by either posting a question with two upvotes or an answer which received at least one upvote.

Before posting inflammatory questions, one or two of which I have been guilty of doing myself in the past, go through the site, visit the sections "votes" and "active" to get a clearer idea of how ELU works and next time, make sure you know what you are talking about.